# Making a simon says game but not starting. Using Corona sdk, lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to code a game similar to simon says. I am currently using corona sdk as my platform. I have written out all my code, but it seems that when I start it, it does not run through my algorithm and does not make a random pattern. It is supposed to run the algorithm once I click on 'Click to Start', but nothing happens. I tried various ways, as well as debugging it, but it seems that I can't find the right solution to this.

I'll post all of my code just in case anything is wrong.

Here's the code:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- main.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

count = 0
pat = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
-->Adds background image

local background = display.newImage("wallpaper.jpg")

local startText = display.newText("Click to Start!", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 40)
startText.x = display.contentWidth/2
startText.y = display.contentWidth/4
startText:setTextColor(255,110,110)

-->Adds Boxes - row 1
local box1 = display.newImage("my_box.png")
box1.x = display.contentWidth/5
box1.y = display.contentWidth/2
local btnclick1 = display.newImage("clickedbox1.png")
btnclick1.x = display.contentWidth/5
btnclick1.y = display.contentHeight/3

local box2 = display.newImage("my_box.png")
box2.x = display.contentWidth/2
box2.y = display.contentWidth/2
local btnclick2 = display.newImage("clickedbox1.png")
btnclick2.x = display.contentWidth/2
btnclick2.y = display.contentHeight/3


local box3 = display.newImage("my_box.png")
box3.x = display.contentWidth/1.25
box3.y = display.contentWidth/2
local btnclick3 = display.newImage("clickedbox1.png")
btnclick3.x = display.contentWidth/1.25
btnclick3.y = display.contentHeight/3


-->Adds Boxes - row 2
local box4 = display.newImage("my_box.png")
box4.x = display.contentWidth/5
box4.y = display.contentWidth/1.25
local btnclick4 = display.newImage("clickedbox1.png")
btnclick4.x = display.contentWidth/5
btnclick4.y = display.contentHeight/1.875


local box5 = display.newImage("my_box.png")
box5.x = display.contentWidth/2
box5.y = display.contentWidth/1.25
local btnclick5 = display.newImage("clickedbox1.png")
btnclick5.x = display.contentWidth/2
btnclick5.y = display.contentHeight/1.875


local box6 = display.newImage("my_box.png")
box6.x = display.contentWidth/1.25
box6.y = display.contentWidth/1.25
local btnclick6 = display.newImage("clickedbox1.png")
btnclick6.x = display.contentWidth/1.25
btnclick6.y = display.contentHeight/1.875


-->Adds Boxes - row 3
local box7 = display.newImage("my_box.png")
box7.x = display.contentWidth/5
box7.y = display.contentWidth/.91
local btnclick7 = display.newImage("clickedbox1.png")
btnclick7.x = display.contentWidth/5
btnclick7.y = display.contentHeight/1.365


local box8 = display.newImage("my_box.png")
box8.x = display.contentWidth/2
box8.y = display.contentWidth/.91
local btnclick8 = display.newImage("clickedbox1.png")
btnclick8.x = display.contentWidth/2
btnclick8.y = display.contentHeight/1.365


local box9 = display.newImage("my_box.png")
box9.x = display.contentWidth/1.25
box9.y = display.contentWidth/.91
local btnclick9 = display.newImage("clickedbox1.png")
btnclick9.x = display.contentWidth/1.25
btnclick9.y = display.contentHeight/1.365

--if the box is clicked, it lights up (by displaying another image over it)--
local onTouchListener = function(event)

    if(event.phase == "began") then

        if (pattern == false and gameOver == false) then

            if(event.target == btnclick1) then
                clicked = 1
                count = 1
                btnclicked1 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
                btnclicked1.x = display.contentWidth/5
                btnclicked1.y = display.contentHeight/3
            elseif(event.target == btnclick2) then
                clicked = 2
                count = 1
                btnclicked2 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
                btnclicked2.x = display.contentWidth/2
                btnclicked2.y = display.contentHeight/3
            elseif(event.target == btnclick3) then
                clicked = 3
                count = 1
                btnclicked3 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
                btnclicked3.x = display.contentWidth/1.25
                btnclicked3.y = display.contentHeight/3
            elseif(event.target == btnclick4) then
                clicked = 4
                count = 1
                btnclicked4 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
                btnclicked4.x = display.contentWidth/5
                btnclicked4.y = display.contentHeight/1.875
            elseif(event.target == btnclick5) then
                clicked = 5
                count = 1
                btnclicked5 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
                btnclicked5.x = display.contentWidth/2
                btnclicked5.y = display.contentHeight/1.875
            elseif(event.target == btnclick6) then
                clicked = 6
                count = 1
                btnclicked6 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
                btnclicked6.x = display.contentWidth/1.25
                btnclicked6.y = display.contentHeight/1.875
            elseif(event.target == btnclick7) then
                clicked = 7
                count = 1
                btnclicked7 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
                btnclicked7.x = display.contentWidth/5
                btnclicked7.y = display.contentHeight/1.365
            elseif(event.target == btnclick8) then
                clicked = 8
                count = 1
                btnclicked8 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
                btnclicked8.x = display.contentWidth/2
                btnclicked8.y = display.contentHeight/1.365
            elseif(event.target == btnclick9) then
                clicked = 9
                count = 1
                btnclicked9 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
                btnclicked9.x = display.contentWidth/1.25
                btnclicked9.y = display.contentHeight/1.365
            end

            if(clicked ~= 0) then

                if(pat[patternIndex]  == clicked) then

                    patternIndex = patternIndex + 1

                else
                    gameOver = true
                end

            end

        elseif (gameOver) then
            started()
            gameOver = false
        end


    elseif(event.phase == "ended") then
                if (btnclicked1 ~= nil) then
                    btnclicked1:removeSelf()
                    btnclicked1 = nil
                elseif(btnclicked2 ~= nil) then
                    btnclicked2:removeSelf()
                    btnclicked2 = nil
                elseif(btnclicked3 ~= nil) then
                    btnclicked3:removeSelf()
                    btnclicked3 = nil    
                elseif(btnclicked4 ~= nil) then
                    btnclicked4:removeSelf()
                    btnclicked4 = nil
                elseif(btnclicked5 ~= nil) then
                    btnclicked5:removeSelf()
                    btnclicked5 = nil
                elseif(btnclicked6 ~= nil) then
                    btnclicked6:removeSelf()
                    btnclicked6 = nil
                elseif(btnclicked7 ~= nil) then
                    btnclicked7:removeSelf()
                    btnclicked7 = nil
                elseif(btnclicked8 ~= nil) then
                    btnclicked8:removeSelf()
                    btnclicked8 = nil
                elseif(btnclicked9 ~= nil) then
                    btnclicked9:removeSelf()
                    btnclicked9 = nil                
                end

    end

end


btnclick1: addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)
btnclick2: addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)
btnclick3: addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)
btnclick4: addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)
btnclick5: addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)
btnclick6: addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)
btnclick7: addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)
btnclick8: addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)
btnclick9: addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)


--if started, starts algorithm--
local started = function(event)

    if (event.phase == "ended") then

        pat = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
        random = math.random()
        patternIndex = 0
        light = 2
        clicked = 0
        count = count + 1
        pattern = true

        if (startText ~= nil) then
                    startText:removeSelf()
                    startText = nil
        end

        --if started--
        if(math.mod(count,20) == 0) then
            clicked = 0

            if(light >= 0) then
                light = light - 1
            end

        end


        if (pattern) then

            if (light <= 0) then

                if (patternIndex >= table.getn(pat)) then
                    --randomizes lights--
                    clicked = math.random(1,10)+1
                    table.insert(pat,clicked)
                    patternIndex = 0
                    pattern = false

                else
                    clicked = pat[patternIndex] 
                    patternIndex = patternIndex + 1
                end

                light = 1

            end

        elseif (patternIndex == table.getn(pat)) then
            pattern = true
            patternIndex = 0
            light = 2
        end

    end
end

startText: addEventListener( "touch", started)
```

Answer (score 0):

First error I noticed is that in the function onTouchListener you're checking value gameOver which is not initialized (that means it is set as nil) and your condition will be never passed.
put this code into onTouchListener event

```
print("pattern = "..pattern.."   gameOver = "..gameOver)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the information! can you look at my updated post and evaluate it if u have the chance!

heres the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259005/tried-debugging-still-dont-know-why-the-code-is-not-working